# Add multiple dragable and resizable images to canvas

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a online shopping website project. For that i need to add multiple images like belts, cap, shirts or trousers to canvas. Finally the canvas should be imported as an image.

Some one suggest me how to do and also help me in adding multiple dragable and resizable images to canvas. Please help me out

This is what i tried to do.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Outfit Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(event){
$("#shirt").resizable().draggable();
   $('.pic1').live('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).resizable().draggable();
});
});
  var shirt;
  var pant;
  function selectshirt(src)
  {
  shirt = src;
  path = "<img class=\"pic1\" src=\""+src+"\" height=\"300px\" width=\"300px\"/>";
  invisible("shirtcontainer");
  visible("pantcontainer");

  document.getElementById("shirt").innerHTML=document.getElementById("shirt").value+path;
  document.getElementById("cart").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function selectpants(src)
  {
  pant = src;
  path = "<img class=\"pic1\" src=\""+src+"\" height=\"400px\" width=\"300px\"/>";
  document.getElementById("trousers").innerHTML=path;
  }
  function addtocart()
  {
  alert("Shirt:"+shirt+"\npant:"+pant);
  }
  function changeshirt()
  {
  visible("shirtcontainer");
  invisible("pantcontainer");
  }
  function changepant()
  {
  visible("shirtcontainer");
  invisible("pantcontainer");
  }
  function visible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function invisible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="leftpanel" style="position:absolute;left:0;width:33%;">
<div style="left:0;height:30%;" id="shirt"></div>
<div style="left:0;height:70%;" id="trousers"></div>
<div style="left:0;height:70%;" id="cart">
<button  onclick="changeshirt()">Change Shirt</button>
<button  onclick="addtocart()">Add to cart</button>
</div> 
</div> 
<div id="middlepanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;left:500;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
<div id="shirtcontainer">
<img src="images/shirts/shirt1.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt2.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt3.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt4.png" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt5.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt6.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/shirts/shirt7.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
</div>
</div> 
<div id="rightpanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
<div id="pantcontainer">
<img src="images/pants/pant1.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant2.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant3.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant4.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant5.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant6.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
<img src="images/pants/pant7.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
</div>
</div>


</body>
<script>
invisible("pantcontainer");
invisible("cart");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This are pretty complex things to do in a canvas since you're going to have to handle all the mouse picking, event capture, redraw, etc.. on your own. I suggest you look into a canvas library that can handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

i have done for 10 shirts and 10 trousers, now i am going to make it dynamic. but for those who need code can refer to this. It may help you.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Outfit Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // sets draggable the elements with id="shirt"
  $('#shirt').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
    containment: '#leftpanel'    // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  // sets draggable the paragraph inside #trousers
  $('#trousers').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    // removes all LI with class="cls" in OL
    $('#shirt').resizable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  $('#trousers').resizable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: '#leftpanel'      // sets to can be dragged only within its parent
  });
  });
});

  var shirt;
  var pant;
  function selectshirt(src)
  {
  shirt = src;
  path = "<img src=\""+src+"\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"/>";
  invisible("middlepanel");
  visible("rightpanel");

  document.getElementById("shirt").innerHTML=path;
  document.getElementById("cart").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function selectpants(src)
  {
  pant = src;
  path = "<img class=\"pic1\" src=\""+src+"\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"/>";
  document.getElementById("trousers").innerHTML=path;
  }
  function addtocart()
  {
  alert("Shirt:"+shirt+"\npant:"+pant);
  }
  function changeshirt()
  {
  visible("middlepanel");
  invisible("rightpanel");
  }
  function changepant()
  {
  visible("shirtcontainer");    
  invisible("pantcontainer");
  }
  function visible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function invisible(containername)
  {
  document.getElementById(containername).style.visibility="hidden";
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="leftpanel" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="shirt"  style="left:0;height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
    <div id="trousers" style="left:0;height:300px;width:300px;" ></div>
</div> 
<div style="left:0;height:70%;" id="cart">
    <button  onclick="changeshirt()">Change Shirt</button>
    <button  onclick="addtocart()">Add to cart</button>
    <button id="btn">Resize</button>
</div> 
<div id="middlepanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="shirtcontainer">
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt1.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt2.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt3.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt4.png" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt5.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt6.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/shirts/shirt7.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectshirt(this.src)"/>
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="rightpanel" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:33%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="pantcontainer">
        <img src="images/pants/pant1.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant2.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant3.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant4.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant5.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant6.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
        <img src="images/pants/pant7.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" onclick="selectpants(this.src)"/>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
<script>
invisible("rightpanel");
invisible("cart");
</script>
</html>
```